# How do i stub a method/attribute of all instances of a class based on another attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Either this doesn't exist or i am looking at this the wrong way.

In `rspec`, I want to stub a method/attribute of all the instances of a class but only if that instance follows a certain condition, for example:

the following code will stub all posts with given comments:

`Post.any_instance.stub(:comments).and_return([comment1, comment2])`

but I only want to stub comments if the post is `published`, otherwise i want a blank `comments` array.

Is there any way I can do something like this:

```
Post.any_instance.stub(:comments) do |post|
  post.published ? [comment1,comment2] : []
end
```

I have seen solutions where you send an argument to the stubbed method and based on argument value you can return different values, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've included should work fine. Stubbing with a block is documented in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/old-syntax/any-instance#block-implementation-is-passed-the-receiver-as-first-arg, although it's deprecated now in favor of the new methods described at https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance